# UINavigation bar back button not responding

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a cameraview from which I'm pushing another view of with TableViewController. I can push the second view from my main view by using navbar controller. But the back button from the second view which is table view does not respond. I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance.

@WrightCS Thank you for your immediate response.

In my app delegate.

```
ViewController *vc= [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.window setRootViewController :navController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Right now I'm using a temporary button to push the view.

```
-(IBAction)testButtonPressed {
    TableView *tableVC = [[TableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Pos the code you are using for the views, how you create the second view, etc.

Comment: @WrightsCS Thank you for the immediate response.

Comment: Nothing in your code indicates why the back button does not respond.

Comment: @WrightsCS Is there a method that links to the left back button? Because the back button comes along with the navbar and I only know to push view forward. I'm sorry I'm not very well informed, but it would be kind gesture if you could guide me.

Comment: No, if you push a view on the same stack, then the back button should already be there and linked to go back.

Comment: @WrightsCS Yes!! that's what I thought. And the back button is there too. I have discovered why it's not going back, because the mainview is cameraview and when the second view is pushed the camera is still capturing images which needs to be terminated. The error reads multiple audio/video is not supported. I'm going to work on it and see what happens. But still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons your back button may not work:

- You are using a custom UIButton and the frame/bounds are not correct you can use `[yourButtonName sizeToFit]` 
  to size it properly.
- You are adding a button programmatically and not adding a click event:

  [yourButtonName addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonNameTapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Don't forget your event.

```
...
-(void)yourButtonNamedTapped:(id)sender
{
...
}
```

docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you are using a UINavigationController, back will automatically show up when you use [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerName];

Comment: First of all thank you for taking time to reply to my question. I'm using UINavigationController, hence back button came along. But I have found out the problem and it's fixed too. I read your comments and I'll keep my mind of it for future use. It looks very informative and helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(IBAction)testButtonPressed {
        TableView *tableVC = [[TableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

        UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
        [backBarButtonItem release];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{      
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self  action:@selector(backButtonDidClicked:)];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    [backBarButtonItem release];
}

-(void)backButtonDidClicked :(id)sender
{  
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It should work for you!!